# Magento 1.9.3.7 to 2.3.3 migration after "This site can’t be reached" issue

Tags: magento2, migration

After **Magento 2** migration, I had this error :

> "This site can’t be reached"

In Below Page showing this type message

like:

> 1. Admin
> 2. Cart
> 3. Customer/account/create
> 4. Contact
> 5. login pagees

[image]

Comment: It looks like a fatal error in code or permissions issue. The best bet is to check your server logs.

Answer (score 0):

According to your image, This is not a Magento error but in client side, check this : https://whatsabyte.com/windows/err_connection_refused/

Update :

If some pages works try this :

- Check the folders permission
- Clean the cache
- Clean the **content** of `pub/static`without the .htaccess then deploy the static content : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: not client side but some page working like homepage,category page,view page

Comment: look my update...

Comment: thanks for replay but i have allready deploy command run also but still some pages not working

Comment: What about the folders permission ?

Comment: chmod -R 0777 pub var generated

Comment: How to set theme after migration?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run this command:

```
chmod -R 777 var pub generated
php bin/magento c:c
```

Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

this is the issue of https and http settings which are made magento1 admin. You can remove that from database and check.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen updates of your problem and recommend you try this:

`chmod -R 777 var pub generated`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

I think it should work now. Please tell me if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For fixing this issue need to go these steps:

```
1. Firstly please check the files and folder permissions
2. Make sure in core_config table your base url path update or not
3. .htaccess file is exist or not
```

If you are following steps then now need to hit given below command.

```
chmod -R 777 var pub generated 

php bin/magento setup:upgrade  

php bin/magento setup:di:compile  

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f  

php bin/magento cache:flush  

chmod -R 777 var pub generated
```